# R: Multiply each element < 1 in a list by 10 until the element is > 1

Tags: r, function, vector, apply

x is a double precision vector containing numbers both smaller and bigger than 1:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 0.1, 0.02, 0.003)
```

If an element in x is smaller than one, I would like to multipy that element by 10 until it is bigger than one; if the element is already bigger than one, it should remain unchanged. The result should be a double precision vector again:

```
(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

I feel like this should be very simple, but the solution eludes me. Here is what I did so far. I defined the function times_ten that does the operation described above:

```
times_ten <- function(x) {
  while (x < 1) {
    x <- x * 10
  }
}
```

Then I apply this function to the vector x:

```
y <- sapply(c(1, 2, 3, 0.1, 0.02, 0.003), function(x) times_ten(x))
```

But now y is a list and no longer a double. Even worse, all values in y are now NULL.

Do I have to change the function, and if so, how? Or is there a better approach entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you missed `return` statement within your function.

```
times_ten <- function(x){
      while (x < 1) {
        x <- x * 10
      }
      return(x)
    }
```

with that, your solution is perfectly right.

```
y <- sapply(c(1, 2, 3, 0.1, 0.02, 0.003), function(x) times_ten(x))
```

Here is another solution.

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>% map_dbl(~times_ten(.x))
```

gives me output as

```
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 3):

As [@Neel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61526467/12158757) said, you need `return(x)` at the end of your function `times_ten`.

---

Below is an easier method for the conversion, where `log10()` was used

```
y <- x*10**ifelse(-log10(x)>=1,ceiling(-log10(x)),0)
```

such that

```
> y
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Thanks! I think yours can only work if all in `x` are less than 10

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)